# Call stored procedure from ADF and sink to Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm struggling with calling the stored procedure (create in SSMS, Azure serverless pools) in ADF and sink to AZURE database.

I have a copy data activity, my `Source dataset` is linked to my `synapse analytics` serverless pools:

[image]

My `Sink` is connected to an Azure SQL database  parameter in the `Sink` coming from the  Azure SQL database `Dataset`.

[image]

This is where I want to write output from the stored procedure. Problem is that I could not figure out how I could `TRUNCATE TABLE` in `Pre-copy-Script`.

Comment: Write the truncate table script in pre-copy script text box. Check this [img](https://i.imgur.com/yXsRF9y.png)

Comment: FYI, you can upload images straight onto [so]; please don't upload them to a different site to then have to have us open a webpage and then click on the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a text box for pre-copy script on your 2nd screen dump.

Just add TRUNCATE TABLE YOURTABLENAME in the box. Replacing YOURTABLENAME with the actual name of your table.